# How we can add milestone on case detail page in service cloud

Tags: service-cloud-console

I have created entitlement process and attached milestone after that I added in case page layout also but still not able to show in case detail page.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the milestone component to the page layout. Instructions [here](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=entitlements_milestone_tracker.htm&language=en_US).